# how to get the guild name that have less than 10 members using discord.js in v13

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, nodes

I want to send guild name list in channel that have less than 10 member. {USING discord.js v13}

My code

```js
guild.channels.cache.forEach((channel) => {
        if (channel.type === 'text' && !targetChannel && channel.permissionsFor(guild.me).has("SEND_MESSAGES")) targetChannel = channel
    })


  if(guild.memberCount < 10 ) {
     message.channel.send (guild.name);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do

```js
client.guilds.cache.forEach(g => {
   if(g.memberCount < 10) {
      message.channel.send(g.name) 
   }
})
```